# Jquery .submit() function is not working after .ajax() function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, submit

`Jquery` `.submit()` function is not working after `.ajax()` function
**CODE:**

```
    if ($("#NetBanxFormTag").attr("action") != "") {
    AddOdemeLog($("#<%=TxtCC.ClientID %>").val(),MusteriAdSoyad,$("#<%=HFDrm.ClientID %>").val(), $("#<%=HFbnk.ClientID %>").val(),$("#<%=Txtccname.ClientID %>").val());
    $("#NetBanxFormTag").submit();
    }

function AddOdemeLog(param3, param4, param5, param6, param7) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~//lokasyon.asmx/ODEMELOG") %>',
        data: "{'param1':'<%= VAR_SID %>','param2':'<%= VAR_DID %>','param3':'" + param3 + "','param4':'" + param4 + "','param5':'" + param5 + "','param6':'" + param6 + "','param7':'" + param7 + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var SONUC = data.d;
            $.session.set('JqSes_LogID', SONUC);
        }
    });
```

This code is **working** on desktop browser, but not working on **mobile browser**(iphone safari, chrome etc.)

Comment: can't see .submit() function

Comment: submit() function is in jquery library.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 if ($("#NetBanxFormTag").attr("action") != "") {
    AddOdemeLog($("#<%=TxtCC.ClientID %>").val(),MusteriAdSoyad,$("#<%=HFDrm.ClientID %>").val(), $("#<%=HFbnk.ClientID %>").val(),$("#<%=Txtccname.ClientID %>").val());
    $("#NetBanxFormTag").submit();
    }


function AddOdemeLog(param3, param4, param5, param6, param7) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~//lokasyon.asmx/ODEMELOG") %>',
        data: "{'param1':'<%= VAR_SID %>','param2':'<%= VAR_DID %>','param3':'" + param3 + "','param4':'" + param4 + "','param5':'" + param5 + "','param6':'" + param6 + "','param7':'" + param7 + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var SONUC = data.d;
            $.session.set('JqSes_LogID', SONUC);
        }
    }).done(function(){

$("#NetBanxFormTag").submit();
});
```